# Powershell - Recursivly change path containing a value

Tags: powershell, path, char

I recently started using powershell, cause i find it very usefull and powerfull :)

So this is the scenario : 
Customer have a folder structure that used to have commas in it.
Because of their latest program addition, this fails, due to the commas.
Essentially, they just want to replace the commas with for example " - "

This is what i have.. And it works, but i feel it's inefficient.
The script does what it's supposed to, but as soon as one path is changed, the remaining will fail because the original path have been changed, you follow me? :)

```
    $folderpath = "C:\pathcontainingcomma"
foreach ($i in get-childitem $folderpath -Recurse) {
   $name = $i.name.replace(","," - ")
   Rename-Item -Path $i.fullname -NewName $name -Force -Verbose
}
```

i hope i explained well enough, please ask questions if you have any :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to rename from the inside out to avoid changing paths you still need to process, so I guess the following should work:

```
$folderpath = 'C:\pathcontainingcomma'
$items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folderpath
[Array]::Reverse($items)
$items | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($_ -replace ',', '-') -Force -Verbose }
```

Comment: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
Are we missing something here? i don't see $i anywhere either.. and it wasn't $items, then i get this error :
Rename-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified meth
od is not supported.

Should it be $items.Name for example ?

Comment: Sorry, copied your code too faithfully.  I just rewrote it using a pipeline since I consider `foreach(){}` usually not a very idiomatic solution in PowerShell.

Comment: And no, `$items` is an array (which gets reversed prior to the actual loop). `ForEach-Object` allows access to the current pipeline element via `$_` (as usual in pipelines involving scriptblocks).

Comment: No problem, I'm still at my learning stage :) , Although shouldn't your code have $_.fullname for the source? , i changed that and then it seems like it worked :)

Comment: `$_` should work too, actually, since it's a `FileInfo` object and thus `Rename-Item` should be smart enough to use the full name from it. Usually at least. But I don't do much with the file system so yes, `$_.FullName` is a reasonable fallback that should definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem $folderPath -r '*,*' -name | foreach {
$p = "$folderPath\$_"; rename-item $p ($p -replace ',',' - ') -whatif }
```

The `-Name` paramete is handy here because the output order with `-Name` would allow you to rename the higher level dirs first and the replace fixes up all the elements of the path as you foreach through the output.